# Is it possible to align on both axis AND stretch content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using flex to display elements horizontally in a div(container). These elements should all be **1.** right and bottom aligned and **2.** stretch full height. I can achieve 1. by itself and 2. by itself but not together, they seem to conflict and stretch seems to override the bottom alignment.

Is there a way I can achieve right, bottom alignment for my inner elements AND make them stretch full height? Note I really cant add another div to wrap the elements.

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* Align inner elements right and bottom */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: solid 1px red;
  }

  .container > * {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    /* Make inner elements stretch full height*/
    align-self: stretch;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container" style="height: 500px;">
    <a href="/#"><p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p></a>
    <p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p>
    <p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p>
    <div>
      <a href="/#"><span>Dropdown Btn</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code currently is 100% height and justified bottom right. If you meant the *content of your inner containers* however, then it makes a little bit more sense.

Here I made the inner containers flexy, but since the inner content is always full width, the right-align doesn't do much, so instead I applied a text-align.

Is this the result you are looking for?

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* Align inner elements right and bottom */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: solid 1px red;
  }

  .container > * {
    border: solid 1px blue;
    /* Make inner elements stretch full height*/
    align-self: stretch;

   /* Because your p-tags has a margin. */
   /* (And it's unclear if you consider that full-height) */
    margin:0;      
   
    /* Align the content of your inner elements */
    display: flex; 
    align-items: flex-end;
    text-align: right;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container" style="height: 500px;">
    <a href="/#"><p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p></a>
    <p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p>
    <p><span>This should be bottom right aligned</span></p>
    <div>
      <a href="/#"><span>Dropdown Btn</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```